# Call * method on implicit receiver

Tags: ruby, dsl

I want to create the next DSL part:

```
* 'Ruby'
```

The next experiment shows predictable results:

```
def *(a)
  a
end

* 'Ruby'         #=> SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting :: or '[' or '.'
self.*(1)        #=> NoMethodError: private method `*' called for main:Object
self.send(:*, 1) #=> 'Ruby'
```

I suppose Ruby syntax analyzer considers such expression as a splat operator or syntax sugar for the asterisk method. Can someone explain this more detailed and (if it's possible) provide solution to resolve my problem?

Comment: Is your problem that you want to call the `*` method with a single argument and not 2?

Comment: No, he wants to define his own method (for some kind of DSL I guess)

Comment: @lifecoder Right ^_^

Comment: You can look at this article for some details which may help - [Ruby’s Unary Operators and How to Redefine Their Functionality](http://www.rubyinside.com/rubys-unary-operators-and-how-to-redefine-their-functionality-5610.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not possible. There are some methods that simply cannot be called without an explicit receiver because they would otherwise be ambiguous. In particular, in every case where you have both a unary prefix and a binary infix operator, it would be impossible to distinguish the two cases:

```
+ a == a.+@()
- a == a.-@()
& a # interpreted as the unary prefix proc-block conversion operator
* a # interpreted as the unary prefix splat operator
```

or in cases where the operator conflicts with other syntax:

```
/ a # interpreted as the start of a Regexp literal
```

For consistency, Ruby forces the use of two operands for *all* binary infix operators, not just the ones for which the grammar would be ambiguous.

Likewise, `[]` cannot be called without an explicit receiver because it would conflict with literal syntax for arrays.

The other well-known example of methods that cannot be called without an explicit receiver, is setters:

```
self.foo = bar # setter
foo = bar      # local variable
```

For `private` setters, there is actually an exception to the rule for `private` methods, that allows them to be called with an explicit receiver, as long as that explicit receiver is the literal pseudo-variable keyword `self`. However, no such exception exists for calling private binary operators or methods like `[]`. (There are proposals to that effect, though.)

Comment: There is also `class` method.

Answer (score 2):

Jörg W Mittag answers why your first expression `* 'Ruby'` (without an explicit receiver) raises an error.

I will add why your second expression `self.*(1)` (with an explicit receiver) raises an error. This is because the method is defined on the `main` object, which are all private by default.

This gives you that the only way to call the method is neither with nor without an explicit receiver, in other words, you cannot call that method with a form of an ordinary method call. You can only pass it in the form of a symbol describing that method, and let another method (`send`) execute it instead.